# FBA not working after windows automatic update in SharePoint 2013 Portal

Tags: sharepoint-2013, windows-update, fba

I have a portal running using claim base authentication (windows and FBA) and enabled anonymous access , it was working fine until 19-06-2022 windows server 2016 ask for restart to install updates, after that the portal is still working only for anonymous access when try to login as FBA form login default page its just refresh without login, dont know why is that and can not login as FBA, also when try to login as windows authentication, its gives an error :

> "System.ArgumentException: Exception of type
> 'System.ArgumentException' was thrown.  Parameter name: encodedValue
> at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimEncodingManager.DecodeClaimFromFormsSuffix(String
> encodedValue) ......."

After check windows update history the updates related to sharepoint is :

> Security Update for Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2013 (KB5002219)

> Security Update for Microsoft SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013
> (KB5002062)

those two updates are released in JUNE 14, 2022.
tried many old solutions all over the net and not fixed
tried to crate new empty web application with enable Windows and FBA authentication also not fixed the issue.
but web application works fine when disable FBA and just enable Windows authentication.
Any suggestion !?

Answer (score 0):

Are you accessing your site via HTTPS/SSL?  If not, that is probably the problem.  Chrome made some changes to it's cookie handling a while ago, and when SharePoint released updates to handle them it broke the ability to login via FBA without SSL.  All of the latest SharePoint updates require the site to be hosted with SSL for FBA login to work.